# Linker keeps showing errors after I changed from DirectX SDK to Windows SDK

Tags: c++, linker, direct3d, direct3d11

I just removed all of the headers that were included in the DirectX SDK and i moved towards the Windows SDK, but once I did, the linker constantly complains about an "unresolved external symbol". The linker shows about 24 errors and most of these errors are about functions that I'm not even using in my game.

Linker errors: `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "union __m128 __vectorcall DirectX::XMVectorMultiply(union __m128,union __m128)`

error LNK2001: `unresolved external symbol "union __m128 __vectorcall DirectX::XMVectorSubtract(union __m128,union __m128)`

error LNK2001: `unresolved external symbol "union __m128 __vectorcall DirectX::XMVector3Normalize(union __m128)`

error LNK2001: `unresolved external symbol "union __m128 __vectorcall DirectX::XMVectorSet(float,float,float,float)`

I have not used XMVector3Normalize(), XMVectorSubtract() and XMVectorMultiply() in my application, but I did use the XMVectorSet().

Most of these functions are part of the DirectXMath.h, so what could be wrong here.

Anyway, I don't know if this will help, but down below are all the headers that i used in my application.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <D3D11.h>                      
#include <dinput.h> 
#include <SimpleMath.h>
#include <D3Dcompiler.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <SpriteFont.h>      //This file also includes DirectXMath.h
#include <DDSTextureLoader.h>
#include <WICTextureLoader.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "D3D11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dinput8.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxguid.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")
```

What can i do to fix these linker problems? I already linked the apropriate libraries and headers using Project->Properties-> VC++ Directories ->Include Directories and Library Directories in Visual Studio 2015.

I've been trying to solve this problem for the past hour or so. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe they're used by something in SpriteFont.h?

Comment: `SpriteFont.h` does not use any of the functions. But it includes the header `SpriteBatch.h`, and this header includes `DirectXMath.h`, `DirectXColors.h`, `functional`, `memory` and `d3d11_1.h`

Comment: Can anyone give me any advice on the matter?

Comment: Are you sure you removed __all__ _DX_ references (in terms of includes)? it seems that here we have an indirect one. The includes (compile phase) and libs (link phase) must be in sync: if you use (directly or indirectly) some func from a _.h_ file, you must link against the corresponding _.lib_ . Also doesn't the link error specify where the undefined symbol is referenced from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The linker keeps complaining after I changed from legacy DirectX SDK to Windows SDK (Visual Studio 2015))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712488/the-linker-keeps-complaining-after-i-changed-from-legacy-directx-sdk-to-windows)

Comment: You already [asked the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712488/the-linker-keeps-complaining-after-i-changed-from-legacy-directx-sdk-to-windows/33839483#33839483).  Please ask just once for help.