# Linker gives errors about a function that i have not used in my application at all

Tags: c++, linker, direct3d, direct3d11

The linker keeps showing a bunch of errors about functions that i have not used in my application. The only thing that I did was change the headers from DirectX SDK to the Windows SDK, and I also downloaded the package for DirectXTK so i can use `WICTextureLoader.h` and `DDSTextureLoader.h`

Here are some of the linker errors.

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "union __m128 __vectorcall DirectX::XMVectorMultiply(union __m128,union __m128)`

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __vectorcall DirectX::XMVectorSinCos(union __m128 *,union __m128 *,union __m128)`

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "union __m128 __vectorcall DirectX::XMVectorSet(float,float,float,float)`

I'm not sure what's going on here. I didn't call `XMVectorMultiply()` or `XMVectorSinCos()` at all in my application. I already linked the appropriate libraries and headers in my project, but this still won't fix the problem. What could be causing these linker errors?

(If you need more relevant information, just ask)

Below is just part of my code (I didn't include all of it because i have about 2000 lines of code):

```
#pragma comment (lib, "dinput8.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxguid.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "D3D11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")

#include <windows.h>    
#include <D3D11.h>                      
#include <dinput.h> 
#include <D3Dcompiler.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <SimpleMath.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <DDSTextureLoader.h>
#include <WICTextureLoader.h>
#include <SpriteBatch.h>
#include <SpriteFont.h> 

void Create_Camera_View_Space()
{

camPosition = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 2.0f, -12.5f, 0.0f);
camDirection = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
camUp = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);



CameraView = DirectX::XMMatrixLookAtLH(
                        camPosition,    
                        camDirection,   
                        camUp           
                        );
}


void Create_Camera_Projection_Space()
{
CameraProjection = DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(
                                    0.4f * 3.14f,       
                                    (float)400 / 400,   
                                    1.0f,               
                                    10000.0f            
                                    );          

}


void Create_World_Space_for_Ground()
{   
DirectX::XMMATRIX Translation; 
DirectX::XMMATRIX Rotation;     
DirectX::XMMATRIX Scale;
DirectX::XMMATRIX Input_Rotation_X;
DirectX::XMMATRIX Input_Rotation_Z;


GroundWorld = DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity();


Scale = DirectX::XMMatrixScaling(500.0f, 10.0f, 500.0f);


Translation = DirectX::XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);

GroundWorld = Scale * Translation;


}
```

This is the few times i am using the functions in the `DirectXMath.h`, but the linker shows errors that come from that specific header..

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: I just edited my original post and put in some code. But I don't think it will help much since the linker errors are about functions that I'm not using in my application

Comment: I found the problem, it seems that everytime i call the function `DirectX::XMVectorSet()`, `DirectX::XMMatrixLookAtLH()`, `DirectX::XMVectorGetX()`, `XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw()` and `XMVector3TransformCoord()`. Everytime I call these functions i get the `unresolved external symbol` error. How can i fix this?

Comment: Don't post [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714883/linker-keeps-showing-errors-after-i-changed-from-directx-sdk-to-windows-sdk).  Modify your original question if you want to make changes.

Comment: What VS compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue here is that you are building the various libraries in question with different settings, compilers, or paths.

`__vectorcall` is a calling convention supported by VS 2013 or later and is used by DirectXMath in the Windows 8.1 SDK and the Windows 10 SDK if it is supported by your compiler. As DirectXMath is all inline, you have to be consistent about making sure all your use of DirectXMath in the same EXE or DLL is using the same version of the headers and the same version of the compiler.

This is one of the reasons why [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) provides compiler specific `vcxproj` files to ensure this is kept in sync.

As your project previously used the legacy DirectX SDK, you probably have some lingering Preprocessor macros and VC++ Directories settings that need cleaned up. You might try doing a diff of your `vcxproj` file with   `DirectXTK_Desktop_2015.vcxproj`.

> You can also have problems if you are building your x86 config with `/arch:IA32` or `/arch:SSE` rather than `/arch:SSE2` which is what is used for the DirectX Tool Kit library builds.
>
> A similar mismatch can happen if you try to use `_XM_NO_INTRINISCS_` in your project which does not match how DirectX Tool Kit is built.

Comment: I think I am using the Microsoft C/C++ Compiler that came in with Visual Studio 2015. It's a little weird because once i made a new project with the same .cpp and .hlsl.... about half of the `unresolved external errors` were solved, and now there's only 4 linker errors left. Why do you think most of the linker errors were solved when i made a new project in Visual Studio 2015? (btw should i change the compiler i use?)

Comment: Re-creating the project likely resolved the configuration issues. How did you add DirectXTK to your project? NuGet or using a ``vcxproj``?  Which ``vcxproj` did you use? What link errors are left?

Comment: I added DirectXTK by using NuGet. In other words, Project->Manage NugetPackages and then i searched DirectX Tool kit 2015. Here are 2 of linker errors that are left ::::: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __vectorcall DirectX::XMVectorSinCos " referenced in function __vectorcall DirectX::XMQuaternionRotationRollPitchYawFromVector` and  `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __vectorcall DirectX::XMVector3IsInfinite(union __m128) referenced in function "struct DirectX::XMMATRIX __vectorcall DirectX::XMMatrixLookToLH` these errors show up everytime i call the functions

Comment: `XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw` and `XMMatrixLookToLH`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Try following the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) tutorials for one of the examples and then add the problem functions.

Comment: Hmm the only thing that i did different in my application is that when i created the project, I used a win32 application instead of a Direct3D win32 application (just like the tutorials that you linked). Will this make a difference whatsoever?

Comment: I can't repro your issue using the Win32 Windows VS 2015 project template either. Try the tutorial and see if it works, then it might be something about your project specifically.

Comment: I tried the tutorials and the linker errors showed up again when i used the `XMMatrixLookAtLH()` function. I made an entirely new Direct3D project that only shows a green window and the error links show up when i use the function. I'm starting to think it might be a bug in Visual studio. I'll consider reinstalling Visual Studio 2015 to see if the problem will be fixed.

Comment: Chuck Walbourn, it turned out to be a bug. I reinstalled Visual Studio and it solved the linker errors. Thank you for your help.