# Everytime I call the functions defined in the DirectXMath.h, the linker gives the "Unresolved External Symbol" error

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2015, direct3d11

I just changed all my headers from the DirectX SDK to the Windows SDK and replaced `xnamath.h` for `DirectXMath.h`. But everytime i call the functions `DirectX::XMVectorSet()`, `DirectX::XMMatrixLookAtLH()`, `DirectX::XMVectorGetX()`, `XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw()` and `XMVector3TransformCoord()`, the linker gives the "Unresolved external symbol" error. I already tried linking the appropriate libraries and headers in Visual Studio 2015, but this didn't change anything.

Down below is my usage of the functions

```
#pragma comment (lib, "dinput8.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxguid.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "D3D11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")

#include <windows.h>    
#include <D3D11.h>                      
#include <dinput.h> 
#include <D3Dcompiler.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <SimpleMath.h>
#include <DDSTextureLoader.h>
#include <WICTextureLoader.h>
#include <SpriteBatch.h>
#include <SpriteFont.h> 

void Create_Camera_View_Space()
{

camPosition = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 2.0f, -12.5f, 0.0f);  //Unresolved External Symbol
camDirection = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //Unresolved External Symbol
camUp = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //Unresolved External Symbol

CameraView = DirectX::XMMatrixLookAtLH(   // Unresolved external symbol"
                    camPosition,    
                    camDirection,   
                    camUp           
                    );
}

void Create_Camera_Projection_Space()
{
CameraProjection = DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(
                                0.4f * 3.14f,       
                                (float)400 / 400,   
                                1.0f,               
                                10000.0f            
                                );          
}

void Create_World_Space_for_Ground()
{   
DirectX::XMMATRIX Translation; 
DirectX::XMMATRIX Rotation;     
DirectX::XMMATRIX Scale;
DirectX::XMMATRIX Input_Rotation_X;
DirectX::XMMATRIX Input_Rotation_Z;

GroundWorld = DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity();

Scale = DirectX::XMMatrixScaling(500.0f, 10.0f, 500.0f);

Translation = DirectX::XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);

GroundWorld = Scale * Translation;
}

void Create_World_Space_for_SkyBox()
{
DirectX::XMMATRIX Scale;
DirectX::XMMATRIX Translation;

SkyWorld = DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity();

Scale = DirectX::XMMatrixScaling(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);


Translation = DirectX::XMMatrixTranslation(
                            DirectX::XMVectorGetX(camPosition),     //Unresolved External Symbol
                            DirectX::XMVectorGetY(camPosition),           //Unresolved External Symbol  
                            DirectX::XMVectorGetZ(camPosition)    //Unresolved External Symbol  
                            );

SkyWorld = Scale * Translation;
}
```

Im not sure if this will really help, but down below are the linker errors

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "union __m128 __vectorcall DirectX::XMVectorSet(float,float,float,float)`

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "union __m128 __vectorcall DirectX::XMVector3Dot(union __m128,union __m128)`

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "union __m128 __vectorcall DirectX::XMVectorSubtract(union __m128,union __m128)`

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "union __m128 __vectorcall DirectX::XMVectorSubtract(union __m128,union __m128)`

What can I do to fix these errors??

EDIT: I already went to the link [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), but this did not solve my problem.

Comment: This means that the library defining said symbols isn't being linked in.

Comment: Which library defines the symbols for the functions in DirectXMath.h then?

Comment: Read the documentation at MSDN.

Comment: by library, i meant the .lib file. Is there a .lib file that defines the functions in `DirectXMath.h`

Comment: Not only is this a duplicate, you've already [asked the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712488/the-linker-keeps-complaining-after-i-changed-from-legacy-directx-sdk-to-windows/33839483#33839483).